# Complex Function Identities

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Newcomer to Complex Analysis, I can't see any reason why these identities wouldn't hold, if taking multi valued log and exp the whole time.

Am I correct?

Comment: The reason is that you might be off by a factor of $2\pi i$. For example, if you use $\log z= \log r+ i\theta$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ then $\log (-1)=i\pi$ but $\log((-1)(-1))= \log 1= 0$ which is different from $\log(-1)+\log(-1)=2\pi i$

Comment: yes but if I take log(z) = ln(r) + i(a + 2nπ) does that eliminate any ambiguity?

Comment: If you fix $n$ then this will not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have issues with ii), iv) and v) if you're not careful about fixing the principal branch. Lets say you define $\log z = \log |z| + i ( \theta + 2 \pi n ) $ with $n$ fixed. Then for ii)
$$ \log (wz) = \log |w| + \log |z| + i ( \theta_w + \theta_z + 2 \pi n)$$
but
$$ \log w + \log z = \log |w| + i (\theta_w + 2\pi n) + \log |z| + i (  \theta_z + 2 \pi n) $$
For iv) we see
$$ \log (\exp z) = z + 2 \pi i n $$
which isn't $z$. Then remember that
$$ z^w \equiv \exp (w \log  z )$$
so you may run into difficulties for v). Notice that everything checks out if you choose the principal branch ($n=0$), but otherwise you have issues.